# How to break text in subsection heading in Beamer using Copenhagen theme

Tags: beamer

I am using Copenhagen theme for presentation. I have problem. Actually the text of my subsection heading is long that it do not appear completely in the upper bar of slide. Please suggest me what should I do?

Comment: You can use the optional argument: `\subsection[Short title]{Test subsection with a really long title and some additional words for the example}`

Comment: You you please create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that shows your current setup?

Comment: \documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\begin{document}
\title[Title]{}
\author[Author]{}
\institute[Test]{}
\date{\today}
\subject{Informatics}
{
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Test subsection with a really long title and some additional words for the example}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table}
Test Section
\end{frame}
\end{document}

Comment: Now as it can bee seen that in 2nd slide the text of subsection does not appear completely and it does not shift to the next, i was having this problem, if anyone can help me out.

Answer (score 3):

Too long titles in the headline are a bad practice.

You can provide a shorter version for the headline using the optional argument for `\subsection`, as in

```
\subsection[A short version of the title]{Test subsection with a really long title and some additional words for the example}
```

The long version will still be used for the eventual ToC(s).

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer} 
\usetheme{Copenhagen} 

\begin{document} 

\section{Introduction} 
\subsection[A short version of the title]{Test subsection with a really long title and some additional words for the example} 
\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{Table} 
Test
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

If you want to use the long title for the headline (I son't recommend this), you can use a `\parbox`:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer} 
\usetheme{Copenhagen} 

\begin{document} 

\section{Introduction} 
\subsection[\protect\parbox{.5\textwidth}{Test subsection with a really long title and some additional words for the example}]{Test subsection with a really long title and some additional words for the example} \begin{frame} 
\frametitle{Table} Test Section 
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```